# Smart PHP compression code

Tags: php, compression

So I saw this smart topic on "Programming puzzles and code golf": *[We're not strangers...](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6043/were-no-strangers-to-code-golf-you-know-the-rules-and-so-do-i)*. The best answer is PHP code printing the lyrics of *[Never Gonna Give You Up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Never_Gonna_Give_You_Up)*. It is only 543 bytes long.

I tried to understand this PHP code, but I can't get how this works. I think it's a grammar based compression, but I have no clue how one could use undeclared constants like in

```
<?php range('-', T);
```

So here is the code. How does this work?

```
<?=str_replace(range('-',T),split(q,"
I justCannaLE?2Gotta >u=Msta=.q
Ng1Nlet? downNrun<rH=5desMt?N>cryNsayRoodbyeNtE< lie5hurt?q

We'T3n each@Jor s8lSg6r hear9<ch: but6;Lo7hyL7BInsideCe both3Cha9Ro: S
We3KeRa45we;QplBq1)O)NgiT, nPgiT
(GqiT? upq howFJeel:
q knowqmeq<= q
YHq8sqo qt's beenqingq'req aqndqmake? q yHq othMqAqay it
q wqDqellq I'mqGqouqIq fqLhq tqerq
NPq
(OohqeTrQqRSna q gqonqve"),"We; n7trangMsL8loT63Ke rules5s8d8I
AJull commit4nt'sChatFKink: of6CHldn'tRetKisJrom<ny@Ruy-/A= if?<sk 42DS'tLE 4?;Lo8bli=L7ee..
O,R1)O,R001)/-..");
```

See [it working on Ideone](http://ideone.com/XoW5t).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's analyze the `str_replace` parameters one by one.

```
range('-',T)
```

The [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function returns an array that has the elements spanning from the first parameter to the second parameter. Characters are considered by their ASCII values, so the result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => -
    [1] => .
    [2] => /
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 3
    [7] => 4
    [8] => 5
    [9] => 6
    [10] => 7
    [11] => 8
    [12] => 9
    [13] => :
    [14] => ;
    [15] => <
    [16] => =
    [17] => >
    [18] => ?
    [19] => @
    [20] => A
    [21] => B
    [22] => C
    [23] => D
    [24] => E
    [25] => F
    [26] => G
    [27] => H
    [28] => I
    [29] => J
    [30] => K
    [31] => L
    [32] => M
    [33] => N
    [34] => O
    [35] => P
    [36] => Q
    [37] => R
    [38] => S
    [39] => T
)
```

Why `T` instead of `"T"`? PHP has a misfeature that makes it evaluate undefined constants as strings with the same content as the constant's name. The constant `T` isn't defined so it's the same as `"T"` which saves two characters for code golf purposes. The same goes for `q` later. If the server has error reporting on, it will show a warning about an undefined constant.

```
split(q,"I justCannaLE?2Gotta >u=Msta=.q...");
```

This splits the string into an array at the `q` characters. Again, this makes for shorter code than using an array literal. The result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
I justCannaLE?2Gotta >u=Msta=.
    [1] => 
Ng1Nlet? downNrun<rH=5desMt?N>cryNsayRoodbyeNtE< lie5hurt?
    [2] => 

We'T3n each@Jor s8lSg6r hear9<ch: but6;Lo7hyL7BInsideCe both3Cha9Ro: S
We3KeRa45we;QplB
    [3] => 1)O)NgiT, nPgiT
(G
    [4] => iT? up
    [5] =>  howFJeel:

    [6] =>  know
    [7] => me
    [8] => <= 
    [9] => 
YH
    [10] => 8s
    [11] => o 
    [12] => t's been
    [13] => ing
    [14] => 're
    [15] =>  a
    [16] => nd
    [17] => make? 
    [18] =>  yH
    [19] =>  othM
    [20] => A
    [21] => ay it

    [22] =>  w
    [23] => D
    [24] => ell
    [25] =>  I'm
    [26] => G
    [27] => ou
    [28] => I
    [29] =>  f
    [30] => Lh
    [31] =>  t
    [32] => er
    [33] => 
NP
    [34] => 
(Ooh
    [35] => eTrQ
    [36] => RSna 
    [37] =>  g
    [38] => on
    [39] => ve
)
```

The final parameter is the target string.

```
"We; n7trangMsL8loT63Ke rules5s8d8I
AJull commit4nt'sChatFKink: of6CHldn'tRetKisJrom<ny@Ruy-/A= if?<sk 42DS'tLE 4?;Lo8bli=L7ee..
O,R1)O,R001)/-.."
```

If you pass arrays to `str_replace()` as needle and haystack, the replacement is done one at a time. For simplicity's sake, let's take just `"We; n7trangMs"` as the taget string and start replacing from `;`. The first step after replacing `"7"` with `"8s"` (the corresponding replacement in the second array):

```
"We; n8strangMs"
```

Then replace `"8"` with `"o "`

```
"We; no strangMs"
```

`";"` with `"'re"`

```
"We're no strangMs"
```

`"M"` with `"er"`

```
"We're no strangers"
```

In short, it's a basic compression algorithm where you find character sequences that repeat inside the original text and replace them with a single character. When decompressing that character is replaced with the original sequence. By running the progress iteratively you can compress the once-compressed text again (`"o s"` => `"8s"` => `"7"`).

Comment: Thanks for this very good answer. What I was missing here is that you replace multiple times. What would be the simplest way to compress the text? (How did the author find the compressed string?)

Comment: The author probably used some compression algorithm. Doing it manually would be a lot of work.

Comment: Could I find the compression code by 'inverting' the uncompression code?

Answer (score 1):

Try it!

Undefined constants are assumed to be strings. This is what it looks like with notices enabled:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant T - assumed 'T' in D:\www\htdocs\test\index.php on line 1
Notice: Use of undefined constant q - assumed 'q' in D:\www\htdocs\test\index.php on line 1
Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in D:\www\htdocs\test\index.php on line 12
We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
[...]
Never gonna say goodbye
Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you
```

Comment: I tried it, and it didn't raise any notice with `T` and `q`. But if I replace those two constants with other letters, notices appear. What would be the purpose of using undefined constants?

Comment: Oh, I see, these are interpreted as strings and they DO raise a notice (they were hidden on the ideone link). But what about the compression part?

Comment: @Imateapot: the purpose is set by the rules of code golf: use as few characters as possible- `T` is two characters shorter than `'T'`

Comment: Yes, of course! But I didn't know `T` would be interpreted as `'T'` and I don't understand how this code can output the lyrics!